# Why does this test fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, mspec

I'm trying to test/spec the following action method

```
public virtual ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword))
        {
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Account.Actions.ChangePasswordSuccess);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Account.Actions.ChangePassword);
}
```

with the following MSpec specification:

```
public class When_a_change_password_request_is_successful : with_a_change_password_input_model
{
    Establish context = () =>
    {
        membershipService.Setup(s => s.ChangePassword(Param.IsAny<string>(), Param.IsAny<string>(), Param.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
        controller.SetFakeControllerContext("POST");
    };

    Because of = () => controller.ChangePassword(inputModel);

    ThenIt should_be_a_redirect_result = () => result.ShouldBeARedirectToRoute();
    ThenIt should_redirect_to_success_page = () => result.ShouldBeARedirectToRoute().And().ShouldRedirectToAction<AccountController>(c => c.ChangePasswordSuccess());
}
```

where `with_a_change_password_input_model` is a base class that instantiates the input model, sets up a mock for the IMembershipService etc. The test fails on the first `ThenIt` (which is just an alias I'm using to avoid conflict with Moq...) with the following error description:

> Machine.Specifications.SpecificationException: Should be of type System.RuntimeType but is [null]

But I *am* returning something - in fact, a `RedirectToRouteResult` - in each way the method can terminate! Why does MSpec believe the result to be `null`?

Comment: The ThenIt is kinda funky. What testing framework is that?

Comment: @burnt_hand, `ThenIt` is (as stated in the question) just an alias for `It` in Machine.Specifications (MSpec), to avoid conflicts with `Moq.It`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of

```
Because of = () => controller.ChangePassword(inputModel);
```

I of course needed

```
Because of = () => result = controller.ChangePassword(inputModel);
```

since without setting the value to `result`, `result` will obviously be `null`. Sigh.